# How to save a figure in matlab with different names for each figure based on the input?

Tags: matlab

I want to save my figure based on the input. 
In my function I have inputs that is dates:

```
2016-08-02
2016-09-02 ect.
```

I want to save the output figure for each date and I want the name to contain the date. Ex:

```
 figure20160802.pdf
 figure20160902.pdf  ect..
```

Started with this code

```
saveas(figure, 'myfigure' yyyy mm dd, pdf)
```

That is obviously wrong. Someone know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `saveas(figure_handle, file_name)` where `file_name` is a string which is the name of the file, including the date and the extension `.pdf`. You don't need a third argument to `saveas`.

If you want to save the current figure, just replace `figure_handle` with `gcf()`

So your question is really how to construct the `file_name` string. For example, if your date is in a string called `the_date` then you can use the `[]` concatenation operators for example:

```
the_date = '20160802';
file_name = ['myimage' the_date '.pdf'];
saveas(gcf(), file_name)
```

If your date string `the_string` contains hyphens and you don't want them in the filename, you'll have to do a little more work to remove the hyphens:

```
the_date = '2016-08-02';
the_date = strrep(the_date, '-', '');
file_name = ['myimage' the_date '.pdf'];
saveas(gcf(), file_name);
```

You may need to modify this depending on how you have the date stored, but you get the idea

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `imwrite(image, [file_name '.png'])` alternatively if you want to save them as pdf you can use: `print(h, file_name, '-dpdf')` where `h` is the handle to you image.

Comment: But I want to save the figure with a name that match the input date. How can i do that?

Comment: use a string to containing the file name. file_name = sprintf(['figure', your_date])